# No result returned from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML Document that I am loading into memory and querying.
The resulting string in the message box below is blank (i.e its not pulling back the value. The file is being loaded correctly and is returning the result. I am using code from my research on how to query XML files.
What am i doing wrong ?

**C# Code**

```
    // Load the recipe            

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test\Recipes\Recipes.xml");          

    var results = (from c in doc.Descendants("recipe")
                   from f in c.Descendants("partnumber")
                   where (string)f.Attribute("value") == "450455-501"
                   select c).ToList();
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("recipe name: ", results[0].Element("recipename").Attribute("value").Value));
```

**XML Document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
    <recipes>
    <recipe>
        <partnumber value="450455-501" />
        <recipename value="porkchop" />
    </recipe>
    <recipe>
        <partnumber value="450455-601" />
        <recipename value="porkchop" />
    </recipe>
    </recipes>
</body>
```

Comment: Look at your format string - you aren't using the value anywhere! Change `"recipe name: "` to `"recipe name: {0}"`. Just a typo, basically.

Comment: If you had checked `results` in the debugger, you would have found that the XDocument stuff was fine. Always use the debugger.